# WCF net.tcp SSL, certificate and username + password authentication

Tags: wcf, ssl, forms-authentication, net.tcp, .net-4.5

I want to build a client-server, WPF-WCF application that should fulfill the following requirements:

- Fast
- Secured communication between clients and server
- If an user wants to use the client application, he should have a certain certificate installed on his machine and also provide a valid username/password pair
- Everything should happen over the internet

So I started working on it two days ago and, after going through almost every example/tutorial I could find that got close to my scenario, I managed to build a WCF service with net.tcp binding that is hosted in IIS (8 I think) and exposes its metadata through a mex endpoint and a tiny little client console application that can connect to the service and call its one and only HelloWorld method.

All was well until I started trying to add certificate based security. I tried countless configuration combinations and techniques but still couldn't get anything working.

At first, I got some specific error messages telling me various things about the server or client certificates not being valid, trusted, or good for anything in any way.
Then I followed these articles, since I need self-signed certificates while developing.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx

Then, I started getting more and more vague error messages until I gave up.
It might very well be that I misunderstood how WCF works since I don't have that much experience with it.

The configuration that worked is this:

- Service configuration

  ```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="TcpServiceBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="TcpServiceBehaviour" name="WcfTcpServer.TcpService">
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://serverName/wcftcpserver/TcpService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" name="TcpServiceEndpoint" contract="WcfTcpServer.ITcpService" />
          <endpoint address="SME" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ServiceMetadataEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Client configuration

  ```
  <configuration>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://serverName/wcftcpserver/TcpService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfTcpServer.ITcpService" name="TcpServiceEndpoint">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/serverName.smth.smthElse.ro" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
  ```

That's, as you can see, the certificate-less configuration.
Any step that I take towards using my self-signed certificates within this configuration, breaks the applications.

I use .NetFramework 4.5.1 for everything.

I would very much appreciate help with this problem. I can provide additional configurations I tried, if needed.

Is this even possible or am I trying in vain?

Thank you!

Comment: It's generally not recommended to have `net.tcp` binding over the internet. A huge part of WCF (especially, over the internet) is security. Generally, the best for Internet scenarios is WsHttpBinding with Message security. As it provides `end-to-end` security and implements WS-* specifications. Here is a helpful article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650874.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, you can support multiple client credentials using what are known as [Supporting Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751480.aspx).

From the linked article:

> The example adds an X.509 binary security token in addition to a
>   username security token. The token is passed in a WS-Security message
>   header from the client to the service and part of the message is
>   signed with the private key associated with the X.509 security token
>   to prove the possession of the X.509 certificate to the receiver. This
>   is useful in the case when there is a requirement to have multiple
>   claims associated with a message to authenticate or authorize the
>   sender.

On the topic of using `NetTcpBinding` over the internet:

`NetTcpBinding` is generally recommended for intranet scenarios. It is advised by much of what I have read to either use `WsHttpBinding` and `BasicHttpBinding` for internet scenarios depending on your requirements. If security is a top concern of yours - the recommended choice is `WsHttpBinding` with `Message` level security.

Guidelines on choosing a binding for an internet scenario: [Internet Binding Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650874.aspx#InternetBindingScenarios).

Comment: Security should not be a reason to choose WsHttp over NetTcp binding - both support client certificates and username/password options, and provide complete transport encryption.

Also, the first item on @Leif's list was "Fast". In that respect, NetTcpBinding will almost certainly produce more compact messages and therefore have better throughput.

Comment: @Rob: You are correct, security should not be a reason to choose `WsHttp` over `NetTcp`. Actually at the time of writing this, I did not believe `NetTcpBinding` supported `Message` level security - Thanks for pointing that out. Interop should be a reason to choose `WsHttp` over `NetTcp` since `NetTcp` is a proprietary protocol utilized exclusively by WCF. There are also custom firewall configurations required to use `NetTcp`. It will outperform other bindings, but since this is an internet scenario - the latency introduced from going over the internet will mask much of the performance gain.

Comment: In fairness, if interop was a primary concern `WsHttpBinding` would not be the way to go and either `BasicHttpBinding` or `WebHttpBinding` (REST) would be better binding choices. Heck, if you were going to go RESTful, then the ASP.NET Web API or another framework would be more appropriate.